# An app to create files and folders from a given structure

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, scripts

I've seen an app for Mac called Structurer (here a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXRjneFTs6Q) which given a structure of files and folders like this:

```
/folder1
/folder2
  /file1
  /folder2.1
    /file2.1
```

will create this files and folders in a existing place.

There is something like that for Ubuntu, or how can i build a shell script to get something like this?

If is possible would be cool also to be able to create files using templates.

Answer (score 1):

The tricky part is that you have files and folders shown the same way, and no simple way to tell them apart.  For file 2.1 there is not a way to tell if it (`/folder2/folder2.1/file2.1`) is actually a folder or a file within folder2.1.

Yes your description says the word `*file*` so we know you mean file, but to a program how could it tell?  A program might tell files from paths because one is followed at the same indentation level with another entry.  BUT, that leads to a set of complicated and confusing rules.

I would suggest you use a keyword or just full qualified names.  The easiest is:

> /folder1/
>
> /folder2/
>
> /folder2/file1
>
> /folder2/folder2.1/
>
> /folder2/folder2.1/file2.1

The trailing slash means "This is a folder and not a file."  Then you can have an easy script like this to create your directory structure.  A couple warnings about this script.

1. the higher level directories must be created first.
2. I prepend a "." to the path so all directories created are relative to the one in which the script is run.
3. I do no error checking for the content of the dir/path file.

> ```
> #!/bin/sh -v
> #
> # builds a directory and file structure.
> # directories must exists before referenced or file in the directory declared.
> #
> # sample input looks like (without the leading #):
> # /folder1/
> # /folder2/
> # /folder2/file1
> # /folder2/folder2.1/
> # /folder2/folder2.1/file2.1
> #
> # make sure we have our one and only input parameter.
> if [ $# != 1 ]; then
>         echo "Usage: `basename $0` input_file_name"
>         echo "input_file_name contains absolute dir paths with a trailing slash,"
>         echo "or absolute file path/name with no trailing slash."
>         exit 1
> fi
>
> # get the file name from the command line
> FILE=$1
>
> # make sure the input parameter specifies a file.
> if [ ! -e ${FILE} ]; then
>         echo "Sorry, the file ${FILE} does not exist."
>         exit 1
> fi
>
> for LINE in $(cat $FILE)
> do
>         LAST=$(echo ${LINE} | awk -F/ '{print $(NF)}')
>         # if file ends with a slash, this value is blank, if it is no slash, this is the file name.
>         if [ "${LAST}XXX" = "XXX" ]; then
>                 # is empty, so it is directory, future feature to check exist already
>                 mkdir ".${LINE}"
>         else
>                 # is not empty, so it is a file
>                 touch ".${LINE}"
>         fi
> done
> exit 0
> ```

This will create the directories and files as shown in the input file.  If the script is called `create.sh` and you have `chmod 755 create.sh` then the command `./create.sh data` will generate your directories and files as described in the data file.